# Group query results by location, client name and month

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, group-by

I have the following tables:

```
location_location
----------------
id       
name     
email             

sales_sale
---------
id
date
total_amount
location_id
client_id

client_client
-------------
id 
name
```

I would like to create a query that gives the SUM of the Sales column and groups the results by month, location and client name as follows:

```
Desired Result:
Location name  /  month /  sum(total_amount) / client_name
San Francisco      Jan        250                CISCO
```

my attempt:

```
select name(select name from location_location),
to_char(date,'Mon') as mon,
sum("total_amount") as "total_amount",
client_amount    
from sales_sale
group by 1,3
order by mon desc

INNER JOIN name ON client_client.id =sales_sale.client_id and 
INNER JOIN location ON location_location.id =sales_sale.location_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You had the right idea in mind, although your syntax was slightly off:

```
SELECT   l.name, 
         TO_CHAR(date, 'MON')
         client_name,
         SUM(total_amount)
FROM     location_location l
JOIN     sales_sale s ON s.location_id = l.id
JOIN     client_client c ON s.client_id = c.id
GROUP BY l.name, 
         TO_CHAR(date, 'MON')
         client_name
```